# industrial grade UVC light design to cause 1st degree burns on skin after 5 second exposure

Tags: light

First of all the base setting, a non realistic world that has humans, and also beings some could be particularly weak to strong UV: vampires, eyeballs of anything that has eyeballs, beings with skin on the soft side of the curve, floating eye monsters (perhaps from a higher dimensional being peeking into this slice of reality). So I was thinking a UV based weapon would have a use, if not outright killing these beings, at least force them to retreat. I dont want to stray too much from realism however, and make your average uv flashlisght with a couple batteries capable of harming anything, so I seek an answer backed by real world physics.

I see we, irl, currently have 100W UVC "ambient" lights and they are supposed to kill 99.9% of bacteria in the whole room they are placed in. And while they can damage any bio surface they hit (including humans), they would require long exposure to generate significant damage, and the being would not perceive the damage until 4-8 hours later. So this is our base weapon that we have to improve.

Of note, these also create ozone, and it seems ozone may boost UV damage besides being potentially toxic to breathe, for humans and plants at least.

So the question, what would be the way to have this lamp cause a minimum of 1st degree burns on human skin within an acceptable timeframe, 5 seconds?

Things to consider:

- Vampires and floating eyeballs tissue is comparable to humans', therefore the question focuses on human skin for simplicity.
- Consider real world applications seem to use ambient light (hits everything all around), versus a possible spotlight (hits a smaller cone), I dont know whether a spotlight would reduce / increase / irrelevant the damage.
- I dont know the effect of reflections/bounces on the damage, I take every surface hit will reduce the power/energy of the light like it happens with visible light.
- UV light may (or not) affect all skin layers at the same time, so to cause a 1st degree burn you'd also cause a 2nd / 3rd degree one.
- As the light will affect the entire flashed surface, it should burn a large area, this doc [Burn Injury Severity Profile](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/resrep22792.7.pdf) gives me the idea that even for 1st degree burns, once you reach a certain area, you also have a 2nd -> 3rd degree burn at the "center" of the burn. Unsure whether ambient / spotlight would have a "focal point", or whether they "cook" you evenly.

Comment: For future reference, please remember that asking more than one question per post is a reason to close questions (click "close" and read "Needs More Focus"). You're asking two questions: should I use a spotlight (or something else)? and how to protect others (especially the user)? I'm wondering how important this is. You already have fantasy in your fiction. In the Blade movies a female protagonist uses a UV spotlight on a fat vampire without harm to herself. On the other hand, while filming *Blade II* dozens of cast were temporarily blinded due to the misuse of UV lighting. (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... Which is a long way of saying that the more "realistic" you try to make this, the less you can use UV as a weapon. I'd vote you stick with the fantasy your story already embraces and ignore the Real World harmful effects of UV. Or, if you want a nod to the danger... have the wielders of such a weapon wear sunglasses.

Comment: A weapon that can be thwarted by shades and sunblock?

Comment: If I resort to fantasy, a question here is not needed, "its magic". Focus on an answer based on physics (which I lack knowledge hence the question), we (readers) can then conclude the feasibility of the weapon on our own.

Answer (score 1):

> So what would be the way to have this lamp cause a minimum of "recoil from pain" damage within an acceptable timeframe, lets say 5 seconds. Would using a spotlight (focused beam) instead improve damage or decrease it?

I'm going to Frame Challenge this particular point from a Weaponry point of View.

What you've described is very similar to the intended effects of 'Less-than-Lethal' weaponry in the real world. From the LRAD system to the ADS. And as such it has the same issue that the real world systems have - which is that Pain compliance has limited effect.

Adrenalin is a helluva a Drug. There's umpteen videos on the internet (I won't link them) where people have sustained horrific wounds (and in some cases fatal wounds) with little to no discernable impact on them - due to Adrenalin.

Absent Adrenalin is the second problem: Will Power - People, *who really want to* can withstand incredible amounts of Pain - the classic case would be a Mother giving birth, or people who have completed Special Forces selection training with fractured limbs or someone undergoing an initiation ritual.

This is something that is often talked about in cases of Police shootings - which is that the main goal is to put enough holes in the target (person being shot) so that their blood pressure drops low enough that they are incapacitated and *physically* cannot fight. The obvious problem is that this usually ends up being fatal.

Secondly - how much damage do you think a determined attacker can do in 5 seconds? Let's assume that the lamp causes enough pain that *anyone* would stop their attack - 5 seconds is a huge window.

An *average* adult male can cover about 30 metres of ground in that time, get off 3-4 rounds *aimed* from a Bolt action rifle, 15 rounds from a Semi-automatic rifle, 5-7 stabs with a knife, push a whole lot of buttons, an average human can probably hit around 10 punches, a trained boxer a bit more.

That is (in terms of a deadly force encounter) a huuuuuuuge window of time to unleash some mayhem.

In short - a weapons system that takes up to 5 seconds to take effect and relies on Pain compliance is dubious at best.

Comment: not an answer, but thank you, I will rephrase so the goal is slightly less ambiguous.

Comment: Agreed, this doesn't answer the question and isn't a frame challenge.